# Correct Client-Server structure for a 3D game

Tags: java, server, synchronization, client

I am making a simple 3D multiplayer game. In the server side I'm making all the calculations for each client/player in-game based on player position and look direction (both should be updated from user input), and then I want to send all resulting triangles/polygons to the client in order to draw to the screen in each frame. I want the client to send to the server in each frame the buttons pressed on the keyboard (so if W and Space are held down, their flags are set to true and sent that way to the server), and also the change in mouse position. Based on that input I change the position of the player in server-side and the look direction of the camera. The way I have it set up now is that both the client and server are infinite loops without delay.

The server goes something like this in each frame/iteration of the loop:

1. Send a message to client that tells it to update mouse (more about that below)
2. Double player speed for the frame if a specific key is pressed
3. Update look direction based of dx and dy (how much the mouse moved since last frame)
4. Calculate next position of player based on which keys are pressed
5. Collision detection, push back player if inside an object or wall
6. Project all scene triangles into 2D based on look direction (camera matrix)
7. Send a message to client that tells it to clear all triangles from list
8. Send the data of each 2D-projected triangle (coordinates and color)

And the client does this in each frame:

1. Send which keys are currently pressed and which are not
2. Call `repaint()` method:

```
@Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        ArrayList<Triangle> trianglesToDraw = new ArrayList<>(updatedTriangles);
        trianglesToDraw.removeIf(Objects::isNull);
        
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        
        for (Triangle t : trianglesToDraw)
        {
            g.setColor(t.color);
            
            int[] xValues = {(int) t.points[0].x, (int) t.points[1].x, (int) t.points[2].x};
            int[] yValues = {(int) t.points[0].y, (int) t.points[1].y, (int) t.points[2].y};
            
            g.fillPolygon(new Polygon(xValues, yValues, 3));
        }
    }
```

It is worth noting that each side has a separate thread which is responsible for handling messages from the other.

In the server side:

```
public void handleClientMessage(String message)
    {
        if (message.startsWith("keys: "))
        {
            String[] keyInfo = message.replaceAll(",", "").split(" ");
            
            for (int i = 0; i < keysPressed.length; i++)
            {
                keysPressed[i] = Boolean.parseBoolean(keyInfo[i + 1]);
            }
        }
        else if (message.startsWith("mouse_update: "))
        {
            String[] mouseInfo = message.split(" ");
            
            try
            {
                mouseDX = Float.parseFloat(mouseInfo[1]);
                mouseDY = Float.parseFloat(mouseInfo[2]);
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                mouseDX = 0;
                mouseDY = 0;
            }
        }
```

In the client side:

```
    public void handleMessageFromServer(String message) throws IOException
    {
        if (message.contains("Update Mouse"))
        {
            mousePosition = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
            
            int centerX = screenWidth / 2;
            int centerY = screenHeight / 2;
            
            robot.mouseMove(centerX, centerY);
            
            float dx = mousePosition.x - centerX;
            float dy = mousePosition.y - centerY;
            
            sendMessage("mouse_update: " + dx + " " + dy);
        }
        else if (message.equals("clear triangles"))
        {
            updatedTriangles.clear();
        }
        else if (message.startsWith("triangle"))
        {
            String[] triangleInfo = message.split(" ");
            Triangle t = new Triangle(
                new Vector(Float.parseFloat(triangleInfo[1]), Float.parseFloat(triangleInfo[2]), Float.parseFloat(triangleInfo[3])),
                new Vector(Float.parseFloat(triangleInfo[4]), Float.parseFloat(triangleInfo[5]), Float.parseFloat(triangleInfo[6])),
                new Vector(Float.parseFloat(triangleInfo[7]), Float.parseFloat(triangleInfo[8]), Float.parseFloat(triangleInfo[9])),
                new Color(Integer.parseInt(triangleInfo[10]), Integer.parseInt(triangleInfo[11]), Integer.parseInt(triangleInfo[12]))
            );
            
            updatedTriangles.add(t);
        }
    }
```

Now my layout is really bad for many reasons:

1. I can barely move the camera because I expect the client to send updated dx and dy and the server to receive it and update it before it makes the new look direction calculation (which is really unrealistic considering the calculation happends only 2-3 O(1) calculations after the original request it sends to the client). What actually happens is that it's almost always 0.0 for both because it won't update in time.
2. The screen keeps flickering because the client isn't synced with the server so it updates the screen without receiving all triangles from the server and clears the screen before.
3. All of the important calculations are performed in server-side, which is something that makes sense in my mind, but it also means that the more clients there will be the slower it will run for everyone since the server has limited resources to calculate everything.

There are probably more problems that I can't think about at the moment but these are the main ones.
Anyways, I need help to figure out a better layout that will at the very least solve some of these problems and prevent some more future ones. I just don't have enough experience with this so I don't really know the best practices in server-client programming.

Comment: You should let the client handle location updates of its character, movement, look direction, etc. Send the data to the server "for confirmation" and to distribute to other players. But the client should optimistically already perform the actions it expects the server to confirm / validate. You should to a lot of stuff client side ASAP and let the server confirm those actions. Not sure about all the triangle stuff, do you actually need / want that kind of server side rendering, that is very sensitive to latency and makes the game fell unresponsive.

Comment: What do you mean by “confirming”? Also when I think about it I don’t really need the rendering to be server-side, it made sense in my head to do most calculations in server-side and have the client only print the data to the screen. I guess my thinking of the ideal client-server model isn’t good.